# Why my ViewPager is so slow?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Inside the dialogFragment I have viewPager with two pages. Every page contains a custom adapter. One adapter with list of spinners, other adapter with list of EditTexts. ViewPager adds adapters fine.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagefragment_newprod, null);

    LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLL);
    ListView listView=new ListView(getActivity());
    ll.addView(listView);

    if (pageNumber==0){
        dropDownAdapter=new DropDownAdapter(getActivity(), fillListAdapter);
        listView.setAdapter(dropDownAdapter);
    } else if (pageNumber==1){
        boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(getActivity(), filledFields);
        listView.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
    }
    return view;
    }
}
```

But it works to slow! Current Adapter (I mean at the curren page) create views every milisecond! Look at this:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 ...
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.addproduct_item, parent, false);
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "====As I said every milisecond...======");
    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addProductEditText);
    editText.setText(p.value);
    return view;
    }
}
```

Even when I focused the EditText this Log.d write messages every milisecond!
Besides that, adapter at the next page works too. I have other Log.d at the other adapter getView and it works when I used different page's adapter!

Please help me to understand what is wrong...(

Comment: Take a look at the [Android holder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html). You should use it in your `ViewPager`.

Comment: Also, using fragments inside a viewPager takes longer to create, takes more memory and is harder to debug that custom views (-> change your ViewPager's pages to customViews instead of fragments). You could also  populate your list (create the adapter, set it) in an asynctask.

Comment: There's not enough code to figure out what is wrong. Most probably you have some loop (indefinite maybe) which adds data into your list adapter, and that leads to extensive notifyDatasetChanged() calls on your adapter.

Comment: @Mathieu de Brito Have you any example how to create such customViews instead of fragments? I have a lot of editTexts in my adapter, and viewPager dosen't like it(

Comment: Thanks everybody) My problem was because of fragment adapter! Its realy to slow! I made simple ViewPager without fragments and now my aplication is fast and furios!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has already been solved in the comments. The solution for the OP was apparently to remove complex fragments and their adapter. However, I also had complex fragments in a tab layout with a ViewPager, and the following solution fixed the slow paging problem:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

The `2` will keep two pages away from the current page in memory. This was enough for me because I had three tabs. Be careful about keeping too many pages in memory, though. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)).